# Merge and compare with in JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I want to perform merging and comparing objects inside in the JSON.

```
StudentJson:[
{ name : "harish",
  empid: "323234",
  exams: "central"
},
{ name : "harish",
  empid: "323234",
  week41: "30",
  week42: "20",
},
{ name : "harish",
  empid: "323234",
  week47: "47",
  week50: "86",
},
{ name : "harish",
  empid: "323234",
  week51: "67",
  week52: "90",
},
{ name : "kishore",
  empid: "783433",
  exams: "state"
},
{ name : "kishore",
  empid: "783433",
  week20: "23",
  week23: "56",
},
{ name : "kishore",
  empid: "323234",
  week30: "75",
  week38: "73",
},
{ name : "kishore",
  empid: "323234",
  week40: "23",
  week41: "86",
},... 
]
```

Expected Json output:

```
StudentJson:[
{ name : "harish",
  empid: "323234",
  exams: "central",
  week41: "30",
  week42: "20",
  week47: "47",
  week50: "86",
  week51: "67",
  week52: "90"
},
{ name : "kishore",
  empid: "783433",
  exams: "state",
  week20: "23",
  week23: "56",
  week30: "75",
  week38: "73",
  week40: "23",
  week41: "86"
}
]
```

Kindly help me to implement in basic JavaScript program.

Comment: You start, we'll help when you get stuck. Please show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Note, Appear `StudentJson` contains syntax errors , duplicate `empid` values ? Trailing commas at within objects at `index`'s `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `6`, `7` within `StudentJson`. Also, `empid` value at last two objects having property name `kishore` is identical to `empid` for objects having property name `harish` , i.e., `"323234"`.

Adjusting above syntax errors and duplicate `empid` values

json

```
    var StudentJson = [
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "exams": "central",
            "week41": "30",
            "week42": "20",
            "week47": "47",
            "week50": "86",
            "week51": "67",
            "week52": "90"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week41": "30",
            "week42": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week47": "47",
            "week50": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week51": "67",
            "week52": "90"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "exams": "state",
            "week20": "23",
            "week23": "56",
            "week30": "75",
            "week38": "73",
            "week40": "23",
            "week41": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week20": "23",
            "week23": "56"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week30": "75",
            "week38": "73"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week40": "23",
            "week41": "86"
        }
    ];
```

js

```
var res = [];
StudentJson.map(function(v, k) {
  if (k === 0) {
    res.push(v);
  };
  if (k > 0 && v.name === res[0].name) {
    $.extend(res[0], v)
  } else if(v.name !== res[0].name) {
    res[1] ? $.extend(res[1], v) : res.push(v)
  };
});
```

```js
    var StudentJson = [
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "exams": "central",
            "week41": "30",
            "week42": "20",
            "week47": "47",
            "week50": "86",
            "week51": "67",
            "week52": "90"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week41": "30",
            "week42": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week47": "47",
            "week50": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "harish",
            "empid": "323234",
            "week51": "67",
            "week52": "90"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "exams": "state",
            "week20": "23",
            "week23": "56",
            "week30": "75",
            "week38": "73",
            "week40": "23",
            "week41": "86"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week20": "23",
            "week23": "56"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week30": "75",
            "week38": "73"
        },
        {
            "name": "kishore",
            "empid": "783433",
            "week40": "23",
            "week41": "86"
        }
    ];

var res = [];
StudentJson.map(function(v, k) {
  if (k === 0) {
    res.push(v);
  };
  if (k > 0 && v.name === res[0].name) {
    $.extend(res[0], v)
  } else if(v.name !== res[0].name) {
    res[1] ? $.extend(res[1], v) : res.push(v)
  };
}); 

$("pre").text(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

> *How i will implement this StudentJson.map function for "N" of student json objects..-user162366*

Try

```
   var res = [];
   StudentJson.map(function (v, k) {
       if (k === 0) {
           res.push(v);
       } else {
           var j = res.filter(function (value, key) {
               return value.name === v.name
           })[0];
           if (j) {
               $.extend(res[$.inArray(j, res)], v)
           } else {
               res.push(v)
           }
       };
       return res
   });
```

```js
var StudentJson = [{
           "name": "harish",
               "empid": "323234",
               "exams": "central",
               "week41": "30",
               "week42": "20",
               "week47": "47",
               "week50": "86",
               "week51": "67",
               "week52": "90"
       }, {
           "name": "harish",
               "empid": "323234",
               "week41": "30",
               "week42": "20"
       }, {
           "name": "harish",
               "empid": "323234",
               "week47": "47",
               "week50": "86"
       }, {
           "name": "harish",
               "empid": "323234",
               "week51": "67",
               "week52": "90"
       }, {
           "name": "kishore",
               "empid": "783433",
               "exams": "state",
               "week20": "23",
               "week23": "56",
               "week30": "75",
               "week38": "73",
               "week40": "23",
               "week41": "86"
       }, {
           "name": "kishore",
               "empid": "783433",
               "week20": "23",
               "week23": "56"
       }, {
           "name": "kishore",
               "empid": "783433",
               "week30": "75",
               "week38": "73"
       }, {
           "name": "kishore",
               "empid": "783433",
               "week40": "23",
               "week41": "86"
       }, {
           "name": "abc",
               "empid": "123456",
               "week30": "123",
               "week38": "456"
       }, {
           "name": "abc",
               "empid": "123456",
               "week40": "789",
               "week41": "012"
       }, {
           "name": "def",
               "empid": "654321",
               "week30": "012",
               "week38": "345"
       }, {
           "name": "def",
               "empid": "654321",
               "week40": "678",
               "week41": "901"
       }];

   var res = [];
   StudentJson.map(function (v, k) {
   if (k === 0) {
       res.push(v);
   } else {
       var j = res.filter(function (value, key) {
           return value.name === v.name
       })[0];
       if (j) {
           $.extend(res[$.inArray(j, res)], v)
       } else {
           res.push(v)
       }
   };
   return res
   });
      
       $("pre").text(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: How i will implement this StudentJson.map function for "N" of student json objects..

Answer (score 0):

You can to do the function

```
var deepEquals = function(o1, o2) {
         var k1 = Object.keys(o1).sort();
         var k2 = Object.keys(o2).sort();
         if (k1.length != k2.length) return false;
         return k1.zip(k2, function(keyPair) {
           if(typeof o1[keyPair[0]] == typeof o2[keyPair[1]] == "object"){
             return deepEquals(o1[keyPair[0]], o2[keyPair[1]])
           } else {
             return o1[keyPair[0]] == o2[keyPair[1]];
           }
         }).all();
       }
    });
```

Think with me, you have the StudentJson with your 8 values and you need to compare one by one.

We can usage a loop:

```
for(var i=0;i < StudentJson.length; i++){

     //Here we do compare the value of the first position with the second position
  if (deepEquals(StudentJson[i], StudentJson[i+1])){
     //This condition is going returning true or false
  }
}
```

Comment: How i will use this in multiple objects. because we were passing only two objects here.
var anObj = JSON.parse(jsonString1);
var anotherObj= JSON.parse(jsonString2);

Comment: I am not sure, how to use this function. can you please share any working example. Thanks.